# Loading issue sprites in a aggregated viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm having trouble placing my issues correctly in an aggregated viewer. I have several models loaded in my viewer, and I want to load all issues in my project independent of in which model/view they were created in.
Right now I am trying to compare the project base point of my Revit models to the globalOffset of the viewer, and then comparing that to the position and viewerState.globalOffset of the issue in question, like so:

```
this.viewer.model.getGlobalOffset().x - 142000 * 3.28084 /* PBP meter -> feet */ + (linkedDoc.details.position.x - linkedDoc.details.viewerState.globalOffset.x)
```

This logic is working half of the time, the times when a specific model is loaded first and the viewer uses that as basis for the globalOffset. When another model loads first the globalOffset doesn't correlate to (some of) the issues. What I think I need is some kind of global coordinate system that I can relate all others to, but I'm not sure what this is if it isn't the globalOffset.

I can't seem to find anyone else having these issues, so I'm not sure how to go about solving it. Should I force the viewer to use a specific globalOffset at init? Is this possible?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - all the models you're aggregating are Revit models using the same reference point, and the issues are defined relatively to the same reference point as well. Is that correct?

Comment: The models are both Revit and DWGs (although the Revit models are loaded first and yes they share coordinate system). Right now I'm loading all issues in the project that has a pin, so that could be pins from DWGs, Revit files, or any other.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - the `AggregatedView` class stores the global offset of the first loaded model, and applies it to subsequently loaded models as well. I'm not sure if there's a way to specify a custom global offset, though.

If you need more control over where the models are placed, you could simply aggregate the individual models yourself by specifying additional options in the `viewer.loadDocumentNode` method (as explained in [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher)). You can also specify something like `applyScaling: 'ft'` to scale all loaded models into a single, consistent unit system.

Comment: Thanks for the help Petr! I'll look into that. Just a thought that just hit me but do you think looking up the model coordinates that the original pin is placed in, then adding the difference between that and the coordinate system of the viewer would work?

Comment: You can try that, but the mapping process might be a bit more complex. Perhaps there's gonna be some scaling and rotation that'll need to be applied as well, not just offset.